# How to pass float value to function taking double as reference value

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I have a function whose prototype looks like this:

```
void example (double &var);
```

But, my problem is I might require to call function with some float values as well.
e.g.

```
float temp=10.1;

example(temp)
```

If I do this my code don't compile, probably because of passing float value to double reference variable.

I want to avoid writing the overloaded function for double and float.

Can someone please suggest a cleaner/better way to implement this?

Function is basically a truncate function that truncate the input given & yes the original is modified.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can template it.

```
template<typename T>
void example (T &var)
```

Answer (score 5):

How about a template function?

```
template <typename T>
void example (T &var);
```

The compiler will replace both `float` and `double` usages (keep in mind C++ templates are  macros with type-safety)

Answer (score 3):

Passing small types by reference is not recommended. You'd better have something like `double example(double var);`. That will solve your problem as well.

before:

```
void example(double& d);

double d = ...;
example(d); // unclear if d was modified
```

after:

```
double example(double d);

double d = ...;
d = example(d);

float f = ...;
f = static_cast<float>( example(f) ); // cast required to tell the compiler to allow
                                       // the precision loss
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on what exactly `example` is doing.

- Is it changing the value passed by reference? If yes, you cannot pass `float` to it. Passing by forceful conversion will compile, but would crash at runtime (since you'd be passing 4 bytes, where 8 bytes were needed).
- If it is not changing value, you can just add `const` attribute to it, and pass any basic datatype. It would be: `void example (const double &var);`. If conversion is possible (since it is now treated as `(double)`), compiler wouldn't complain.
- Making it function template may or may not work, and it entirely depends on what function is doing.

Comment: Yes the value passed by reference is changed.
The function is a truncate function that truncate the input given.

Is there any issue making it as template??

As suggested by you?
What I may face?

Thank you.

Comment: Truncate as in what? Truncates the decimals? Splits into two parts? Converts to string and trims? For good answers, you should frame good questions! :)